# How to change text colours in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2

I'm new to iTerm2 and I cannot find settings to change text colourations.
I can only find the colours tab, which just defines what colour "yellow" is for example. But nothing that defines that "prompts" should be "yellow".

I've played with the "minimum contrast" slider as well as "colour presets" under the colours tab, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the font, go to iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Colors > Foreground (color box), and choose a new color there.

That will change the color of all the text. You'll also need to have the Minimum Contrast slider set lower than approximately 80 to notice a color difference.

If instead you want different text elements to be colored differently, like how directories show as a different color than files when you "ls -G" then you can set the LSCOLORS environment variable as described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282185/how-do-i-get-different-colors-for-directories-etc-in-iterm2

...or install ohmyzsh from here: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh